# ValueError: client_id must not be blank using PDF Extract API

Tags: python, adobe

I have followed the steps in Getting Started with PDF Extract API (Python) successfully. The required libraries have been installed in the virtual environment (venv_smed). The source code has no syntax errors. However, when I run the `python extract.py` command the following error is displayed:

```
(venv_smed) bash-3.2$ python extract.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/username/Documents/allAboutPython/python3.11/myapp/pkg_app/adobe_pdfservices_sdk/extract.py", line 56, in <module>
    credentials = Credentials.service_principal_credentials_builder().with_client_id(os.getenv('PDF_SERVICES_CLIENT_ID')).with_client_secret(os.getenv('PDF_SERVICES_CLIENT_SECRET')).build();
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/username/Documents/allAboutPython/python3.11/myapp/venv_smed/lib/python3.11/site-packages/adobe/pdfservices/operation/auth/service_principal_credentials.py", line 82, in build
    return ServicePrincipalCredentials(self._client_id, self._client_secret)
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/username/Documents/allAboutPython/python3.11/myapp/venv_smed/lib/python3.11/site-packages/adobe/pdfservices/operation/auth/service_principal_credentials.py", line 28, in __init__
self._client_id = _is_valid(client_id, 'client_id')
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/username/Documents/allAboutPython/python3.11/myapp/venv_smed/lib/python3.11/site-packages/adobe/pdfservices/operation/auth/credentials.py", line 17, in _is_valid
raise ValueError(f'{name} must not be blank')
ValueError: client_id must not be blank
(venv_smed) bash-3.2$
```

The example code has been taken from the following link:
https://developer.adobe.com/document-services/docs/overview/pdf-extract-api/quickstarts/python/

I have reviewed the documentation in Adobe Developer and it seems `ServiceAccountCredentials.Builder` is deprecated.

The section of the code that has problems is the following:

```
credentials = Credentials.service_principal_credentials_builder().with_client_id(os.getenv('PDF_SERVICES_CLIENT_ID')).with_client_secret(os.getenv('PDF_SERVICES_CLIENT_SECRET')).build();
```

I have modified the format of the line of code to obtain the credentials to access the API,

```
credentials = Credentials.service_principal_credentials_builder().with_client_id(
os.getenv('PDF_SERVICES_CLIENT_ID')).with_client_secret(
    os.getenv('PDF_SERVICES_CLIENT_SECRET')).build();
```

When executing the `python extract.py` command I get the same error, however apparently the problem is in obtaining the value of the environment variable  `PDF_SERVICES_CLIENT_SECRET`,

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/username/Documents/allAboutPython/python3.11/myapp/pkg_app/adobe_pdfservices_sdk/extract.py", line 58, in <module>
    os.getenv('PDF_SERVICES_CLIENT_SECRET')).build();
                                             ^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/username/Documents/allAboutPython/python3.11/myapp/venv_smed/lib/python3.11/site-packages/adobe/pdfservices/operation/auth/service_principal_credentials.py", line 82, in build
    return ServicePrincipalCredentials(self._client_id, self._client_secret)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/username/Documents/allAboutPython/python3.11/myapp/venv_smed/lib/python3.11/site-packages/adobe/pdfservices/operation/auth/service_principal_credentials.py", line 28, in __init__
    self._client_id = _is_valid(client_id, 'client_id')
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/username/Documents/allAboutPython/python3.11/myapp/venv_smed/lib/python3.11/site-packages/adobe/pdfservices/operation/auth/credentials.py", line 17, in _is_valid
    raise ValueError(f'{name} must not be blank')
ValueError: client_id must not be blank
```

The pdfservices-api-credentials.json file has the following content in JSON format,

```
{
 "client_credentials": {
  "client_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "client_secret": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
 },
 "service_principal_credentials": {
 "organization_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
 }
}
```

Any guide to resolve the error would be appreciated:

> **ValueError: client_id must not be blank***

Solution:

```
"""
Read JSON
"""

# Opening JSON file
f = open('pdfservices-api-credentials.json')

# returns JSON object as 
# a dictionary
data = json.load(f)

# Get client ID and credentials
CLIENT_ID     = data["client_credentials"]["client_id"]
CLIENT_SECRET = data["client_credentials"]["client_secret"]

print(CLIENT_ID)
print(CLIENT_SECRET)

# Closing file
f.close()

credentials = Credentials.service_principal_credentials_builder().with_client_id(
CLIENT_ID).with_client_secret(
    CLIENT_SECRET).build();
```

The result of executing the script is as expected:

```
(venv_smed) bash-3.2$ python extract.py
"your client_id"
"your client_secret"
Structured Information Output Format 
Introduction 
List of key components 
(venv_smed) bash-3.2$
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Are you wanting to read from the environment variable or the json file? In your code, it's clear you are trying to grab the environment variable. But mentioning the json file makes me wonder how you have your environment setup to properly read your values. If your json file has the valid data you need, have you tried loading the data to grab the `client_id` in there?

Comment: @idjaw - I want to read the two environment variables from the JSON file. Apparently the error is reported when using the .build() method. Do you have any ideas on how to address the problem?

Comment: I provided an answer if I understood correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON file does not contain an environment variable in the way that your code is trying to read it. With what your code is doing right now, it is expecting within the (assuming you are running this in a shell) shell, an environment variable to be set.

What this means is, when running the following (in your shell):

```
export PDF_SERVICES_CLIENT_SECRET
```

the expectation is that you *should* have something returned. This is what your current Python code is expecting when you run this:

```
os.getenv("PDF_SERVICES_CLIENT_SECRET")
```

That `os.getenv` is trying to read the value from your shell environment. It has nothing to do with the JSON file.

So, the error you receive `ValueError: client_id must not be blank` is in fact correct in the sense that the `client_id` was never read as expected by your code in the first place. So it is in fact an empty `client_id` when passed to your function.

You seem to want to read from the JSON file. The JSON file does not contain an environment variable. Your JSON file is simply data that you need to load in to memory and parse through. You can do this through the `json` library. Below is a sample code:

```
import json

with open("pdfservices-api-credentials.json") as f:
    data = json.load(f)
 
print(data["client_credentials"]["client_id"])
```

What is happening in the above code is that the `json` library is used to load a file object (per the `open` method), and once loaded you will have a Python dictionary (assuming your data structure provided is as you have it). From there you simply access what you need per the `print` call.

Comment: Fantastic. I followed your recommendation and the validation of the credentials was perfect and the script ran smoothly as silk. Thank you so much!!! PS. I have added the code that solved the error in case others who are in the same situation want to implement it.

Comment: @Ramiro - Glad to hear. Good luck!